# Solr 7.5.0, error sorting a "pdate" field in ascending 'asc' direction

Tags: sorting, date, solr

by usign the Solr7.5.0 webUI, I am trying to sort a field of my schema "data_creazione", by setting:

**&fl=data_creazione:[2017-11-12T00:00:00Z TO NOW]&sort=data_creazione asc**

my complete query URL being:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/NUR/select?fq=data_creazione:[2017-11-12T00:00:00Z%20%20TO%20%20NOW]&q=regione%20lazio&sort=data_creazione%20asc
```

When i inspect the results I am observing a **strange** and **erroneous** sorting behavior:

- results from 0 to 9 (start=0,rows=10) are correctly ordered (from 2018-03-01 to 2018-03-02)
- results from 10 to 19 (start=10,rows=10) are correctly ordered (from 2018-03-05 to 2018-03-07)
- results from 20 to 29 (start=20,rows=10) **are incorrectly ordered** (from **2018-02-23** to **2018-03-1**)

Moreover, I am trying to send the *same query* to Solr 7.5.0 from a .netcore2.1 application by using the Solr.net driver, and I am returned **the same identical sort error**.

NOTICE: when I try to query the *same query* but in DESCENDING 'desc' direction all things go fine. All results' pages are correctly ordered.
This error does not appear with Solr 7.2.0: ascending and descending sorting over date fields works fine

In my managed-schema the field "data_creazione" is declared this way:

```
<fieldType name="pdate" class="solr.DatePointField" docValues="true"/>
...
<field name="data_creazione" type="pdate" multiValued="false" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
```

Comment: Did you reindex (completely) after changing to the pdate type? Can you create a set of documents that can replicate this issue from scratch with an empty index?

Comment: All documents've been indexed after managed-schema updated. Also, I can provide U the set of  documents that replicates the problem. Tell me how...

Comment: ... or get'em here: [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/edf850d0ad55caa2fa2f52638fd3ce7320181113123846/c54faa817e9b8f9479c7d6f26218a19e20181113123846/682acb?utm_campaign=WT_email_tracking&utm_content=general&utm_medium=download_button&utm_source=notify_recipient_email)